# When initializing a variable with an underscore function, is it best to use .slice(0) for arrays and _(obj).clone for objects?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

The title might be a bit confusing.

Consider the following examples in the underscore docs:

**[Reject](http://underscorejs.org/#reject)**

`var odds = _.reject([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], function(num){ return num % 2 == 0; });
=> [1, 3, 5]`

**[Find Where](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere)**

Note: I added `var oFound = ...`

`var oFound = _.findWhere(publicServicePulitzers, {newsroom: "The New York Times"});`

Would it be considered best practice to use .slice(0) in the reject example and _(obj).clone() in the find where example? This would make sure that the newly initialized variables are not references to the inputs of the underscore functions. For instance:

`var odds = _.reject([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], function(num){ return num % 2 == 0; }).slice(0);`
`var oFound = _(_.findWhere(publicServicePulitzers, {newsroom: "The New York Times"})).clone();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Firstly, the function won't have retained a copy of the value it's returning to you anywhere, and secondly, if it did, it would be up to the function to decide whether it was appropriate to return you a direct reference to that or a copy of it. Adding `slice` or `clone` (unless you have a specific reason to) would just create objects for no purpose.

Remember that the array `reject` returns to you is **not** the array that you fed into it; it's a *new* array containing only the entries that weren't rejected. (If it happens that any of those entries are object references, then of course both arrays have references to the same objects — and would be if you used `slice` as well.)

The purpose of `findWhere`, on the other hand, is to find the object *in the list* and return a reference to that object to you. Presumably you have a reason for wanting to access that object (perhaps you want to change it). Unless you have a specific reason for doing so, not only is copying it unnecessary, but it may actively defeat your reason for finding it in the first place.